# How to diable break line, keystroke (enter e.g) in JTextArea in Swing java

Tags: java, swing

I have `JTextArea` with max chars using `DocumentFilter` filter 
and has `rows,cols` defined.

but the user may press enter and i DONT WANT THIS ENTER TO HAPPEN.

how to disable it?

I Tried [Removing new line function when enter button is pressed Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717828/removing-new-line-function-when-enter-button-is-pressed-java)
but did not work and did not look good in coding.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [disable enter coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/342364/GUI/java/JScrollPane-JTextArea-Disabling-Keyboard-Events)

I used the below code and looked simpler after i refactor it.

```
static void disableKeys(InputMap im,String[] keystrokeNames) {              
        for (int i = 0; i < keystrokeNames.length; ++i)
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keystrokeNames[i]), "none");
    }

disableKeys(textArea.getInputMap(),new String[]{"ENTER"});
```

Comment: See also [*How to Make and Remove Key Bindings*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto).

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use the following line code ?

```
myTextArea.getDocument().putProperty("filterNewlines", Boolean.TRUE);
```